# How to compare CMap Key Case Insensitive?

Tags: c++, mfc

In the below case,

```
typedef CMap<CString, CString, int, int> MapNameAndId;

MapNameAndId["Dummy"] = 1;

int nId = 0;
if(MapNameAndId.Lookup("dummy", nId))
{
   // It should return true and nId should get updated to 1; Key Cases are different.
}
```

how to achieve this? I can do upper case\lower case for key and while adding into map and while lookup, But need a way like std::map where extra argument function as Comparator where Comparator takes care of it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can derive a class from CString and in it you can redefine the operator ==, or the UINT() operator, the operators are in the way of calculating the hash.

```
class MyString
{
    operator UINT()
    {
        return HashKey(CString(*this).MakeUpper().operator LPCWSTR());
    }


    bool operator==(const MyString& otherMyString) const 
    {
        return (CompareNoCase(*this, otherMyString) == 0);
    }
}
```

Then your list declaration should be

```
CMap<CMyString, CMyString&, int, int&>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to store everything lowercase, and then search with lowercase argument

Comment: But as in std::map , we can provide an argument as comparator function, Is it available for CMap?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the key in uppercase or lowercase, and write custom code to convert the input search string into the key's case.

Unfortunately, unlike `std::map` which supports custom comparisons, `CMap` doesn't offer that level of customization:

```
template< class KEY, class ARG_KEY, class VALUE, class ARG_VALUE > 
class CMap : public CObject
```

As you can read, there's no option for a custom comparator.

In general, even in MFC applications, I would encourage you to use the **STL** container class templates, which are designed much better than the old MFC containers.